# Local SVN repository without server

Tags: svn, netbeans, version-control, tortoisesvn, local

I would like to know if it is possible to create a local SVN repository without having to install a server on my machine.

I have heard about [VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) and [SubversionEdge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion) but they both require installing a server, something that is too much for what I need (just keeping track of the versions of 2 or 3 personal websites that I only modify every few months).

I know that I can create a local repository with Tortoise and explore it. The question is: as it doesn't have a server, can I connect to that repository from Netbeans?

I would like to know if the solution to my problem is to create a local repository with Tortoise because I can connect to it from Netbeans or if there is another solution to create a local repository.

Thanks!

Comment: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-access

Comment: I guess that means that with the appropiate URL Netbeans will be able to use the SVN repository?

Comment: The easiest way to have the answer is to try it.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure that not only it works, but it is the best solution.

Comment: 1. Why is it worth installing a SVN server on my own computer if I just need control version once every 1-2 months and it will be from my own computer?
2. Why GIT instead of SVN?

Comment: This is very broad but. 1. because if your computer crashes, you'll lose everything, so the repo should not be served by your own machine 2. because it's better designed, and becoming the de facto standard.

Comment: 1. I can backup my repositories the same as I back up the rest of my files... The server option does not guarantee protection against a crash by itself.
2. How can I use GIT? What software is needed?

Answer (score 0):

If Netbeans can open and use 'file:///'-served repositories, you can created by TortoiseSVN repositories without any headaches (just create it, add some content, copy repo-URL /of trunk?/ from repo-browser and try it)

In any case, you can run *lightweight* `svnserve` (part of SVN CLI-tools, which can be installed with TortoiseSVN) *on demand* for getting `svn://` type of repositories if `file:///`-repository will fail for some resons